# Slick JS does not show the css

Tags: magento2, css, plugin, slider

I've added slick.js to my website,there is no error log.

I put css in **my_vendor/my_theme/web/css**

But I don't think the css had been loaded,b/c when I open the developer tools,

there is no slick.css or slick-theme.css.

Now the page messed up.

Am I missing something ?

----Update----

I try to copy all the css from **slick.css** or **slick-theme.css** to my css.file,and it still not showing the style.

Any idea? :(

Comment: Do you have a specific page you would like to load the css on, such as catalog/product/view, or do you want it to load on all pages?

Comment: Right now just for homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have not included your css files in any page layouts. You can add css files to pages by adding the css file to a layout xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::path/to/slick.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Something similar to this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Swatches/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml#L10

Comment: I think I  gave the wrong src path ,I just make it work by putting the css in own theme.css .Thanks , now I'll follow your way and try to separate it.